# resizing thousands of objects with fixed height and preserving aspect ratio in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, resize

Sorry for my English, I'm a French speaker :D

I would like resize thousands of objects with the same height, but with different widths, and the goal of keeping each of their original aspect ratios.

I've found this discussion:
[Inkscape 0.91: Scaling several objects while keeping their original location](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51806/inkscape-0-91-scaling-several-objects-while-keeping-their-original-location)

If I choose % it will increase all objects, but with different heights.
If I choose PX and I set a number in pixels 300px for example, the individual aspect ratios are not kept ! :'(

A script for achieving exactly the result I want is part of this question and answer:
[Batch script to resize height of all layers to same height but keeping their original aspect ratio](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99230/batch-script-to-resize-height-of-all-layers-to-same-height-but-keeping-their-ori)

But it's specifically written to work for Photoshop :/

Does anyone know how to reproduce this same method in a script for Inkscape?

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want this:

- Switch to selection tool
- Create an object that has the height you need
- Copy the object to the clipboard
- Activate the lock icon in the selection tool's tool controls
- Select all the objects that you want to have that height
- Select Edit > Paste Size > Paste height separately

Do you still need to script this, or is this enough for your needs?

Comment: Just a big Thank you ! This is a very good answer. I knew that I didn't need a script for that, but answers I had from a french forum insisted to script it :/ Thanks a lot ! Have a very nice day, take care :)

Comment: In my case, it changes the height but the corresponding width is wrong. In other words, the aspect ratio of each object is not respected. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @BosonBear Is the lock icon active and are you using a current Inkscape version? Some intermediate version broke this (don't remember which, 1.0, maybe?), but it works in 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with Image Resizer for Windows.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/image-resizer-for-windows-10/9nwwmh081ddb?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

- select all the pictures you want to resize
- right-click the selected files to bring up the quick menu
- click "Resize Pictures"
- select "Custom"
- set your desired dimensions (width x height)
- [since you mentioned you want the heights all the same, but the widths will vary, just oversize the width number to a dimension bigger than any of the final pictures will be]
- uncheck "Make pictures smaller by t not larger"
- uncheck "Resize the original pictures (don't create copies) [at least until you're comfortable with the utility]
- click "OK"

See screenshot of the dialog box:

[image: screenshot of the dialog box]

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted the question. It is about 1000 objects in one image, not 1000 images.